# How to load xml to a dataset if this is empty

Tags: c#, sql, service, web, asmx

I have a dataset that is brought in after executing a stored procedure via my webservice. If the dataset is empty, I need to return a generic result instead of nothing. XML is returned, below my WebService (.ASMX) code, is the .XML spit out if it's EMPTY....not sure if it helps, but I'm completely at a loss here. Ideally, I'd like to see if Table1 exists, then do something....but again, I'm at a loss. Thanks!

```
public DataSet GetMaleDogsDS()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        //Define the dataset, in this case dsDogs
        DataSet dsDogs = new DataSet();
        //
        dsDogs.Tables.Add("Dogs");
        DbCommand dbCommand = null;
        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        try
        {
            Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();

            string sqlCommand = "sp_GetDogs";
            dbCommand = db.GetSqlStringCommand(sqlCommand);
            dbCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "Gender", DbType.String, "male");
            dsDogs = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand);
            string strXml = dsDogs.GetXml();
            return dsDogs;
        }

        catch
        {

            string strXml = js.Serialize(dsDogs);
            return dsDogs;
        }

    }
```

Here is the XML for an EMPTY result:

```
<DataSet xmlns="http://0mitted.net/">
<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
<xs:element name="Table">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="DogID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="LongDesc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ShortDesc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ThumbURL" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="LargeURL" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Gender" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Age" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Weight" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="HealthStatus" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ActivityLevel" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="PersonalityTraits" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="InteractionDog" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="InteractionCat" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="ChildRequirement" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="FenceRequirement" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="WorkSchedule" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="LeashManners" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="TrainingNeeded" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="AdoptionStatus" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="AdoptionFee" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="behavior" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"     xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"/>
</DataSet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to check if your dataset is empty and if this condition is true load a xml file to your dataset:

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    dataSet.ReadXml("input.xml", XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
    //...
}
```

In your scenario this code would fit in like this:

```
dsDogs = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand);
if (dsDogs.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
{
     dsDogs.ReadXml("empty.xml", XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
}
return dsDogs;
```

Comment: Genius! I will let you know if this works out, because that fits my needs precisely!

Comment: Where should I stick that bit? I've tried where, in my brain, seems logical which would be right after the return statement, however the lack of my breakpoints being set off, indicates it (read 'something') is not working.

Comment: Well I guess you wanna check if dsDog is empty after your execute statement. So put it after this line: 'dsDogs = db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand);'

Comment: PERFECT! Works beautifully. Thanks!